# How use Either with async function

Tags: typescript, either, fp-ts

I'm learning `fp-ts` now and try to replace some parts of my API with its approach.

Simple example:

- get `itemId` with request
- use this `itemId` with async function to get (or not) the item

The only way I found is:

```js
 const itemId: E.Either<string, Item["id"]> = pipe(
    body.itemId,
    E.fromNullable('Item ID is missed')
 );
 
 const item: E.Either<string, Item> = E.isLeft(itemId)
    ? itemId
    : pipe(
      await getItem(itemId.right),
      E.fromNullable('cant find item')
    );
```

It works. But is it right way? Is it any way to do it all in one `pipe` function?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few layers to this question so I'll present a possible solution and walk through how it works.

First, `fp-ts` uses [`Task`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Task.ts.html)s to represent asynchronous work, so most of the time when working with async code in `fp-ts` you first convert the code to a `Task` or [`TaskEither`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/TaskEither.ts.html) (more on that in a second). First, we need a function to perform the `getItem` task and return an `Either` instead of `null` when null is returned. This can be defined as:

```js
import * as TE from 'fp-ts/lib/TaskEither';
import * as T from 'fp-ts/lib/Task';
// flow is function composition and avoids some syntax.
// This can be thought of a "point-free" although internally I use a
// not point-free function.
const getItemTE: (id: number) => TE.TaskEither<string, Item> = flow(
  getItem,
  // A task must be a function with no arguments that returns a promise,
  // This takes the result of calling getItem and returns a function that
  // returns that response in order to match the Task interface
  (promisedItem) => () => promisedItem,
  // We convert that task into a `TaskEither`, to get the type we want,
  // but note that this value will never be `left` because the underlying
  // task was returning `Item | null`. Both of those values are considered
  // a Right.
  TE.fromTask,
  // Converting to a TaskEither allows us to chain, which will hand us the
  // unwrapped `right` value and expects us to return a new TaskEither.
  // In this case, we want the task either we get by converting null
  // values into Eithers using the `fromNullable` function.
  TE.chain(TE.fromNullable("can't find item")),
);
```

Now we have a function that takes a number and produces a `TaskEither` which will fetch the item.

Next you want to use this function with your `body` object. You can use the newly created function along with `body` to get an item:

```js
// Note: at this point the Promise will be created so
// any IO is going to be kicked off here, not when the value
// is eventually awaited.
const item: TE.TaskEither<string, Item> = pipe(
  body.itemId,
  // This will wrap up the value into a task either
  // which enables us to chain.
  TE.fromNullable('Item id is missed'),
  // Now we just chain with the newly created function.
  // If the value is `right` then the value is fetched,
  // otherwise the 'Item id is missed' value is stored
  // in left and is returned.
  TE.chain(getItemTE)
);
```

Finally, you can do something with the value as follows:

```js
async function doSomethingWithItem(item: TE.TaskEither<string, Item>) {
  pipe(
    // The item will already have been fetched at this point due
    // to the way the code is written. If you want to avoid fetching
    // the object right away, you might need to change around
    // the line where I went from the `getItem` response to a Task
    await item(),
    E.fold(
      (err) => console.error(err),
      (item) => {
        console.log(`Got item with id: ${item.itemId}`);
      },
    )
  );
}

doSomethingWithItem(item);
```